# Conditional class on $first item in array using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs, angular-material

I am building an app that pulls and displays a list of time slots from a database using ng-repeat.  I also have a navigation that pulls and displays the month/day from the same database using ng-repeat.  When you click on one of the days in the nav, ng-click will filter the list of times that match the day chosen...this all works.

My issue is having the first nav array item activated so the user will know which day they are starting from - the below screen is the first view and although th times below are for the first array item; you wouldn't know because theres no class to it. I was wondering if there is a way to conditionally set `ng-class="$first ? 'active' : ''"` until another link was clicked? Obviously just setting $first works, but it stays active even when choosing another date. Below is the code for the nav.  I am using angular-material for the ui and ui-router for my router.  In the image below you'll notice that JAN FRI 30 is the first item displayed in the array.  Thank you for your help.

```
<ul hide-gt-sm>
        <li ng-repeat="day in times">
          <md-button class="md-primary"
                      ui-sref-active="{{day.date}}"
                      ng-click="filterMobileTimes(day.date.fullDate)"
                      ng-class="$first ? 'active' : ''">
            {{day.date.month}}<br>{{day.date.day}}
          </md-button>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

[image]

Comment: why don't you make current day the active state and let ui-sref-active to handle the rest?

Comment: Can you give me an example...I am still fighting through my Angular skills.  Thank you.

Comment: nm i go mixed up by the use of the ui-sref-active i assumed there was an ui-sref attached you can do something like ng-class={active:(activeIndex==$index)} and then when you click an option you make ng-click="activeIndex=$index; ...."

Comment: This does not add the active class to the first item, which is a 2px solid bottom-border, but does when you make a selection.  It seems that it only adds the class when ng-click is activated.  This has been the biggest part of my headache today..it shouldn't be this difficult.  Is there any way to trigger the $first item on page load as if someone manually selected it? Thank you Dayan for helping me.

Comment: you just need to initialize activeIndex in 0 or make ng-class ng-class={active:(activeIndex?activeIndex==$index:$first)}

Comment: That was it....you rock!  An end to two days waisted....thank you.

Comment: would you mind marking my answer as accepted?

Comment: thx  have a great one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

out of the simples ways of achieving this are

```
<ul hide-gt-sm ng-init="activeIndex=0">
    <li ng-repeat="day in times">
      <md-button class="md-primary"
                  ng-click="activeIndex=$index; filterMobileTimes(day.date.fullDate)"
                  ng-class={active:(activeIndex==$index)}>
        {{day.date.month}}<br>{{day.date.day}}
      </md-button>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

or w/o initializing

```
<ul hide-gt-sm>
    <li ng-repeat="day in times">
      <md-button class="md-primary"
                  ng-click="activeIndex=$index; filterMobileTimes(day.date.fullDate)"
                  ng-class={active:(activeIndex?activeIndex==$index:$first)}>
        {{day.date.month}}<br>{{day.date.day}}
      </md-button>
    </li>
  </ul>
```